# Django: Inject code post pk/id generation and before save in DB

Tags: python, django, django-models, initialization, primary-key

TL;DR: Is there a way to inject code post pk / id generation but before the object is saved in the db?

Hello,
So I am currently working on duplicating django objects. I have a duplicate function which enforces new object generation upon saving by setting pk and uid to None on a deep clone of my object:

```py
def gen_uuid() -> str:
    """Return a str representation of a uuid4"""
    return str(uuid4())


class Entry(PolymorphicModel):
    """Base class providing a custom lock permission, a name and a uid to replace Django's default id DB column."""

    uid = models.CharField(
        unique=True,
        primary_key=True,
        db_index=True,
        default=gen_uuid,
        max_length=36,
        help_text="Object's primary key, it cannot be enforced and will be generated randomly. "
        "Example: c8daa3ac-3dd0-44e9-ba2a-b0cbd1c8d8ae.",
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Name of the object.")
    folder = models.ForeignKey(
        Folder,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="files",
        help_text="Primary key to the folder containing the object.",
    )
    content = JSONField(
        default=dict, blank=True, help_text="JSON representation of the graph."
    )
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Handles entry saving and duplicate management

        This function is overridden so the models can be created with the name.
        This function does not fill missing duplicate numbers.
        It will create duplicates in such pattern:
        entry_name
        entry_name (2)
        entry_name (3)
        """
        # Does some stuff... duplicate() is not called in this function
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    def duplicate(self):
        """Handles duplicate behavior
        Meant to be used as: entry.duplicate().save()
        """
        if not self.pk and not self.uid:
            return self.save()
        # Duplicates the existing object
        duplicate = deepcopy(self)
        duplicate.pk = duplicate.uid = None
        return duplicate
```

I have a problem where in my `content` field there is generated data in the save function.
Among this `content` metadata there is a "uid" field which I cannot fill because it has been set to none and the new pk / uid hasn't been set yet.

Is there a way to inject code post pk / id generation but before the object is saved in the db?

Comment: Signals might help you. Take a look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/. 
I think ```pre_save``` will help you

Comment: Nope, the problem is pre-save happens at the start of save `save()` method while pk is generated after the return `super().save(*args, **kwargs)`. I have to modify my metadata post `return super().save(*args, **kwars)` but before it gets in DB (and especially after the `default` of my uid field is resolved). Maybe `post_save` could do it but I wonder if my pk is generated.

Comment: I managed to do what I wanted by forcing my uid (which wasn't my initial objective) but it works so far. I still wonder when does `default=` resolve.

Comment: Anyway, duplicate probability of uuid is too low (0.00000000006 (6 × 10−11)) to worry about it. If your project is not a crucial one which require high accuracy then default is fine enough